# Task cancellation based on Task ID

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

.Net 4.5

I have a list of tasks

```
List<Task> lTasks
```

each task has its own

> 'CancellationTokenSource' and 'cancellationToken'

The

> Task.Id and Task.status

are listed in a DataGridView.

Each row in the DataGridView also has a button called 'StopTask'.

If user clicked on 'StopTask'button, that specific task should be cancelled based on

> Task.Id

How can I do something like that?

Here is my method that creates a new Task every time it is called

```
 private void CreateNewTask(int RowIndex)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); //Init new CancellationTokenSource
            var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
            try
            {
                var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start new task");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["OutputValue1"].Value = i;
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }

                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                }, cancellationToken);

                lTasks.Add(t); //Add to Liast of tasks (List<Task>)

                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["TaskID"].Value = t.Id;
                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["TaskStatus"].Value = t.Status;
            }
            finally
            {
                cts.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

[UI with DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsET.png)

---

Based on the answers and comments, I did the following and it seems it works fine.

I used DataGridView as my 'Dictionary' and saved the token of each task in

```
dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["RowIndex"].Tag = cts;
```

I also used

> RowIndex

as a unique ID, because two tasks may have same TaskID.

New tasks are created as shown below:

```
 private async void CreateNewTask(int RowIndex)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); //Init new CancellationTokenSource
            var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
            try
            {
                Task t = Task.Run(async () => //Task.Run automatically unwraps nested Task types!
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Start new task");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            // inside this loop the Token cancellation has no effect, it will keep running until this loop is finished then it will throw a cancellation exception
                            dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["OutputValue1"].Value = i;
                            await Task.Delay(300);
                        }

                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                    {
                        ShowMsgBox.Show(ex.Message, "Cancelation", enumMessageIcon.Information, enumMessageButton.OK);
                    }

                }, cancellationToken);

                lTasks.Add(t); //Add to Liast of tasks (List<Task>)

                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["TaskID"].Value = t.Id; //The TaskId is not guaranteed to be unique
                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["TaskStatus"].Value = t.Status;
                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["RowIndex"].Value = RowIndex;
                dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["RowIndex"].Tag = cts;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMsgBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", enumMessageIcon.Error, enumMessageButton.OK);
            }
        }
```

and task can be cancelled as shown below

```
   private void dataGridView_TaskList_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
                e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name is "StopTask")
                {
                    //TODO - Button Clicked - Execute Code Here
                    int.TryParse(dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RowIndex"].Value.ToString(), out int RowIndex);
                    CancellationTokenSource cts_ToBeCancelled = (CancellationTokenSource)dataGridView_TaskList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RowIndex"].Tag;
                    cts_ToBeCancelled.Cancel();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: put `cts` to Rows's Tag ...

Comment: Good idea, I will try it

Comment: The Id is not guaranteed to be unique, so don't use it for such purposes.

Comment: Guids aren't guaranteed to be unique either, perhaps provide context or scope for your admonishment?

Comment: @NineBerry is right, two tasks may have same TaskID. therefore, I used the RowIndex in the DataGridView as a unique ID

Comment: As I side note add this code at the start of your application: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` ... and notice if this makes your application to crash and burn. You should not update the UI controls from any other thread except the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Add the task ids with cancellation token source to a dictionary, from there you can pull out the cancellation token by id.

`Dictionary<int,CancellationTokenSource> taskLookup = new Dictionary<int,CancellationTokenSource>();`

...

`var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>`
...
`taskLookup.Add(t.Id, cts);`

Also, you can't dispose of the `CancellationTokenSource` and then use it later to cancel.

Comment: The dictionary goes at the class level, not in the method btw.

Comment: if the task is finished, I do not need to cancel it, therefore I am disposing the ,,,CancellationTokenSource ,,,

Comment: The task isn't necessarily finished at the point you dispose it.

Comment: But at the moment of the dispose, your task has been launched but it not likely to be finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `cancellationToken.Cancel();` to cancel a taks.

However, inside your task you need to check whether it was cancelled or not. This probably means that inside your for loop you should add the following:

```
if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // Clean up here, then...
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Note that Thread.Sleep in tasks is a bad idea as this will block on thread from the threadpool. Use `await Task.Delay` instead

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); was only for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to resolve it I drived from Task class and added and identifire to MyTask class and in construction injected GUID to distinguish the task.

```
public class MyTask : Task
{
    public Guid Identifire;

    public MyTask(Action action, Guid identifire) : base(action)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Guid identifire) : base(action, cancellationToken)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action action, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Guid identifire) : base(action, creationOptions)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Guid identifire) : base(action, cancellationToken, creationOptions)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action<object> action, object state, Guid identifire) : base(action, state)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action<object> action, object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Guid identifire) : base(action, state, cancellationToken)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action<object> action, object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Guid identifire) : base(action, state, creationOptions)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }

    public MyTask(Action<object> action, object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Guid identifire) : base(action, state, cancellationToken, creationOptions)
    {
        Identifire = identifire;
    }


}
```